# Notification Not Appearing On Watch

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I'm creating the following notification in my app:

```
        int notificationId = 001;

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon)
                        .setContentTitle(StationUtils.getStationModeString("My Notification")
                        .setContentText("Good Notification");

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(MainActivity.this);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

It appears on my phone, but it doesn't appear on my watch connected to my phone.  Is there something missing from the code that's required for Android Wear?  Does it have to be a release signed build?  I checked settings and the watch does have access to notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android 5.0 be sure that interuption settings are not set to `"None"`.

[Silence your device with "Do not disturb"](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295)